# Creating Tests at Runtime

Tags: .net, testing, test-framework

Are there any .NET testing frameworks which allow dynamic creation of tests without having to deal with a hokey Attribute syntax?

Something like:

```
foreach (var t in tests)
{
  TestFx.Run(t.Name, t.TestDelegate);
}
```

But with the test reporting as you would expect...

I could do something like this with RowTests et al, but that seems hokey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how i can use parameterized tests to sorta do this here.

http://richarddingwall.name/2009/06/08/using-nunit-to-check-your-ioc-container-is-set-up-right/

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if [Pex](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/) would suite your needs...